# Running multiple websites (with different hostnames) on AppHarbor?

Tags: appharbor

Do I need to have separate/multiple workers to run multiple websites (each with a unique domain) on AppHarbor? I'm using a VPS now to run 5 different websites and it's very cost effective, but thinking about moving to something like AppHarbor or Azure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the one account (username/pass), you would set up each site with it's own free Canoe plan.

To each plan you would then need to add the $10/m for custom hostnames, which lets you point your domain name at the site. For a total of $50/m

https://appharbor.com/pricing

Multiple workers (the paid plans) are designed to scale one site to handle more traffic, not to host multiple sites under the one plan.

Comment: Thanks Chris... This going to cost a lot more than I anticipated if I have to pay $10/m for each hostname and then potentially $10/m for the SQL Nano add-on for each site. That would be $100/m as apposed to $25/month with my current VPS hosting plan at SoftSys, where I can have an unlimited number of hostnames and databases. Thanks again.